# C# - Receive object as parent interface and typecast one of child class

Tags: c#, polymorphism

New ASP.NET core (to the whole web thing actually). So, making controllers and also started implementing Interfaces for scalability (my code base is pretty big, and already feeling the heat implementing Interfaces too late down the line). I have a couple of classes like this -

```cs
public interface IParent {
    string IParent1 { get; set; }
    string IParent2 { get; set; }
    string IParent3 { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass1: IParent {
    public string IParent1 { get; set; }
    public string IParent2 { get; set; }
    public string IParent3 { get; set; }

    string ChildClass11 { get; set; }
    string ChildClass12 { get; set; }
    string ChildClass13 { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass2 : IParent {
    public string IParent1 { get; set; }
    public string IParent2 { get; set; }
    public string IParent3 { get; set; }

    string ChildClass21 { get; set; }
    string ChildClass22 { get; set; }
    string ChildClass23 { get; set; }
}
```

I need to send an object which is of type ChildClass1 or ChildClass2 from my Angular/Typescript website (the json model is either `ChildClass1` or `ChildClass2`), and one of my controllers will receive this -

```cs
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(IParent parent)
{
   if (parent is ChildClass1)
   {
       // Do something
   }
   if (parent is ChildClass2)
   {
       // Do something else
   }
   // Rest of the controller
   ...
}
```

Now the issue is, the arg `parent` of the controller is only receiving whatever properties it has. I.e. properties of `childclass`s are not deserialized and doesn't even exist (because the `parent` doesn't have them I think).

Can someone kindly suggest how to solve this, please? I would like the `parent` arg to hold full `ChildClass1` or `ChildClass2` variables and then typecast and perform their related operation.

Apologies if somethings doesn't make sense. Please let me know if you need more information. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you have separate actions for each child type? If there is common code to be performed on each one, you can break that out into a separate method which accepts an `IParent` object and pass the child object from each child's action.

Comment: Thought of making separate controllers first. But wasn't sure if that is anti-pattern. Yea, if you guys think that is way to go, I'm totally fine with it!

Comment: That's the way I would do it.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for your advise. Working as lone wolf on my team, wished many times that I work in a full team with other developers so I can have local help. SO never lets me down. Thank you very much, everyone!

Comment: Usually `dto` classes don't use interfaces

Comment: Ah, yes!. It makes sense to not use interfaces on DTO's the more deeper I am going. The classes above are pure DTO's, they don't perform any work other than representing the data models. Are interfaces to be used only for regular classes that perform some real work?